# Cows And Grass: A 3 By 3 System Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

2 cows in 4 weeks can eat all the grass on 2 acres and all the grass that grows on these 2 acres during the 4 weeks. 3 cows in 2 weeks can eat all the grass on 2 acres and all the grass that grows on these 2 acres during the two weeks. How many cows can eat in 6 weeks all the grass on 6 acres and all the grass that grows on these 6 acres during the 6 weeks? Assume the grass has a constant growth rate and is distributed evenly.

---

I feel like I should use a 3 by 3 system to solve this problem but I only got to:

$x$= amount of grass 1 cow eats in a week

$y$= amount of grass that grows on an acre per week.

What should I do next?

Comment: You also need z = initial amount of grass per acre

Comment: @WW1  That's what I'm missing!  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a 3 by 3 system.

let a be the amount of grass that can grow in 1 acre in one week

Case 1:the amount of grass consumed by the cows is
$$
2+4\times 2\times a
$$
Then the rate at which one cow can eat is simply
$$
\frac{(2+4\times 2\times a)}{2\times 4}
$$
Case 2: the amount of grass consumed by the cows is
$$
2+2\times 2\times a
$$
And so the rate at which one cow can eat is 
$$
\frac{(2+2\times 2\times a)}{3\times 2}
$$
Now we set the expressions from case 1 and case 2 equal:
$$
\frac{(2+4\times 2\times a)}{2\times 4}=\frac{(2+2\times 2\times a)}{3\times 2}
$$
We get a = 0.25 acres/week

So the rate at which one cow can eat is 0.5 acres/week (after substituting it back into one of the two expressions)

Case 3: the amount of grass consumed by the cows is
$$
6+6\times 6\times a=6+6\times 6\times0.25=15
$$
So the rate at which one cow can consume grass is
$$
\frac{15}{6\times (number\;of\;cows)}
$$
Since we know one cow can eat at a rate of 0.5 acres/week
$$
\frac{15}{6\times (number\;of\;cows)}=0.5
$$
$$
number\;of\;cows=5
$$